# sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' when installing package in R (Windows 10)

Tags: r, windows, eof, install.packages

I am attempting to install a package from a local source and I am getting an error I am unfamiliar with. Here is the code:

```
pkg1 <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dnapath/dnapath_0.6.7.tar.gz"
install.packages(pkg1, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Here's the error:

```
* installing *source* package 'dnapath' ...
** package 'dnapath' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include' -I'C:/Users/user name/private OneDrive location/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/RcppArmadillo/include'     -fopenmp    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf:245: RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'dnapath'
* removing 'C:/Users/user name/private OneDrive location/R/win-library/4.1/dnapath'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/THOMPS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpYTi7OQ/downloaded_packages/dnapath_0.6.7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

From my research, this means there's an unclosed/extra ' or " somewhere in the code for installing the package. Is this correct and is there a way to tell which of the files being referenced contains to improper syntax? I checked the RcppExports.cpp file mentioned in the error, but didn't see anything jumping out. Apologies if this is a silly question (still new to the world of coding) and any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!